# Applescript - Create Incrementing Variable Name in Repeat?

Tags: applescript

I am new to scripting so I may not know how to search for a solution to this; so far I have not found an answer. Is is possible to change a variable name within a loop?

I would like to create a loop that makes a new variable for each list value. This code works right now, but how would I change the If statement to a Repeat?

```
choose from list {"1 Apple", "2 Banana", "3 Cat", "4 Dog", "5 Elephant"} with title "What columns do you want?" with multiple selections allowed
set listreturn to result
set numfields to count of listreturn

if numfields is equal to 1 then
    set field1 to word 1 of item 1 of listreturn as integer
else if numfields is equal to 2 then
    set field1 to word 1 of item 1 of listreturn as integer
    set field2 to word 1 of item 2 of listreturn as integer
else if numfields is equal to 3 then
    set field1 to word 1 of item 1 of listreturn as integer
    set field2 to word 1 of item 2 of listreturn as integer
    set field3 to word 1 of item 3 of listreturn as integer
else if numfields is equal to 4 then
    set field1 to word 1 of item 1 of listreturn as integer
    set field2 to word 1 of item 2 of listreturn as integer
    set field3 to word 1 of item 3 of listreturn as integer
    set field4 to word 1 of item 4 of listreturn as integer
end if
```

Trying something like this:

```
repeat numbfields times
    set field(repeatcount) to word 1 of item (repeatcount) of listreturn
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create dynamic variable names at runtime.

A solution is to put the `field` variables into another list.

```
set fieldList to {field1, field2, field3, field4, field5}

choose from list {"1 Apple", "2 Banana", "3 Cat", "4 Dog", "5 Elephant"} with title "What columns do you want?" with multiple selections allowed
set listreturn to result
if listreturn is false then return
repeat with i from 1 to count listreturn
    set item i of fieldList to word 1 of item i of listreturn as integer
end repeat
```